# Why the test script keeps on failing to complete the test script execution? JEST nodejs testing Timeout error

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a very simple middleware to test using jest. The middleware uses mongoose odm

```
// auth.service.ts
attachAutoUser = async (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('ATTACH SYSTEM USER ');
    console.log('emal:', req.globalconfig.AUTO_USER_EMAIL);
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.globalconfig.AUTO_USER_EMAIL }).select(`firstName lastName email role`).exec();
    console.log('user: ', user);
    
    return next();
  }
```

**My test script:**

```
// auth.service.test.ts
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

import AuthService from '../../../server/auth/auth.service';
const auth = new AuthService();

jest.setTimeout(30000);

describe('AuthService', () => {
  
  // 
  describe('attachAutoUser middleware', () => {
    const mockRequest: any = {
      globalconfig: {
        AUTO_USER_EMAIL: 'test@abc.com'
      }
    };
    const mockResponse: any = {
      json: jest.fn()
    };
    const mockNext: NextFunction = jest.fn();

    it('should call next()', async () => {
      await auth.attachAutoUser(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext);
      expect(mockNext).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
  })

});
```

**Run command:**

```
$ npm test /tests/server/auth/auth1.service.test.ts -- --detectOpenHandles --runInBand --collectCoverage
```

**Log Detail:**

```
------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                    | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s                                                                                                      
------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
All files               |   24.79 |     9.09 |   10.99 |   24.84 |                                                                                                                        
 server                 |   57.14 |    80.49 |   42.86 |   57.14 |                                                                                                                        
  config.ts             |   47.62 |    80.49 |      25 |   47.62 | 77-94,175-181                                                                                                          
  server-stream.ts      |   85.71 |      100 |   66.67 |   85.71 | 6                                                                                                                      
 server/api             |   22.39 |        0 |    4.35 |   22.73 |                                                                                                                        
  base.ts               |   22.39 |        0 |    4.35 |   22.73 | 8-13,16-18,24-28,34-38,45-52,56-61,66-68,74-86,93-95,101-104,111,119-123,132                                           
 server/api/auditLog    |      40 |        0 |       0 |      40 |                                                                                                                        
  auditLog.model.ts     |      40 |        0 |       0 |      40 | 17-39                                                                                                                  
 server/api/funeralHome |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                                                                                                                        
  funeralHome.model.ts  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                                                                                                                        
 server/api/role        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                                                                                                                        
  role.model.ts         |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                                                                                                                        
 server/api/tenant      |   33.33 |        0 |       0 |   33.33 |                                                                                                                        
  tenant.model.ts       |   33.33 |        0 |       0 |   33.33 | 70-77,81-97                                                                                                            
 server/api/user        |   14.81 |        0 |       0 |   14.81 |                                                                                                                        
  user.model.ts         |   14.81 |        0 |       0 |   14.81 | 20-43,88-90,100-102,116-121,128-133,140-157,162,170-204,226-306                                                        
 server/auth            |    18.5 |        0 |    8.82 |   18.39 |                                                                                                                        
  auth.service.ts       |    18.5 |        0 |    8.82 |   18.39 | 33-44,51-69,72-80,86-88,93-245,257-283,295-318,330-365,380-393,402-418,431-474,482-600,608-611,620-623,628-636,644-649 
 server/version         |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                                                                                                                        
  index.ts              |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                                                                                                                        
------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        105.821 s
```

**Error:**

> I keep on getting error: FAIL  tests/server/auth/auth1.service.test.ts
> (105.634 s)   AuthService
> Attach auto user middleware
> ✕ should call next() (100015 ms)
>
> ● AuthService › Attach auto user middleware › should call next()
>
> ```
> : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 100000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not
> ```
>
> invoked within the 100000 ms timeout specified by
> jest.setTimeout.Error:
>
> ```
>   20 |     const mockNext: NextFunction = jest.fn();
>   21 | 
> > 22 |     it('should call next()', async () => {
>      |     ^
>   23 |       await auth.attachAutoUser(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext);
>   24 |       expect(mockNext).toHaveBeenCalled();
>   25 |     })
> ```

Why the test script is not completed executing without timeout erro? WHat might be the issue? Any help will be appreciated.

**Fix:**
As Christian indicated, I forget to mock / stub the database call.
Here is the fixed solution, in case someone else is stuck with the similar mistake.

```
  describe('attachAutoUser middleware', () => {
    const mockRequest: any = {
      globalconfig: {
        AUTO_USER_EMAIL: 'test@abc.com'
      }
    };
    const mockResponse: any = {
      json: jest.fn()
    };
    const mockNext: NextFunction = jest.fn();

    it('should call next()', async () => {
      const UserFactory = {
        successResponse: {
          // user: 'the user OBJECT'
          user: {
            firstName: 'TestFirst',
            lastName: 'TestLast',
            email: 'test@abc.com',
            role: 'admin'
          }
        },
        failureResponse: {}
      };

      // User.findOne = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
      //   select: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(UserFactory.successResponse)
      // }));

      User.findOne = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
        select: jest.fn(() => ({
          exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(UserFactory.successResponse)
        }))
      }));

      await auth.attachAutoUser(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext);
      expect(mockNext).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Comment: It looks as if your test is doing an actual call to the database? If so, don't you want to stub that call?

Comment: @Christian Yes you are right... I forgot to mock the database call ..

Answer (score 0):

Forget to stub the database call.

Here is the result after fixing the test.

```
describe('attachAutoUser middleware', () => {
    const mockRequest: any = {
      globalconfig: {
        AUTO_USER_EMAIL: 'test@abc.com'
      }
    };
    const mockResponse: any = {
      json: jest.fn()
    };
    const mockNext: NextFunction = jest.fn();

    it('should call next()', async () => {
      const UserFactory = {
        successResponse: {
          // user: 'the user OBJECT'
          user: {
            firstName: 'TestFirst',
            lastName: 'TestLast',
            email: 'test@abc.com',
            role: 'admin'
          }
        },
        failureResponse: {}
      };

      User.findOne = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
        select: jest.fn(() => ({
          exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(UserFactory.successResponse)
        }))
      }));
```